# How to remove the section title in header using scrpage2

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2

I would like to remove the section title (header) in the appendix:

```
\documentclass[headsepline, open=right,twoside=true, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}

    \chapter{Appendix}
    \section{Remove the section title}
    \blindtext[12]

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

I'm looking for something like `\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}` except I want to keep the number and remove the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the KOMA-Script option `appendixprefix` is not used:

```
\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
    \markright{\ifnumbered{section}{\thesection\autodot}{}}%
}}
```

[image]

Using `\ifnumbered` avoids a wrong number in the header if there is an unnumbered section.

Note `\appendix` is not an environment. The package `scrpage2` is depreciated. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead.

```
\documentclass[headsepline,twoside, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{%
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{%
    \markright{\ifnumbered{section}{\thesection\autodot}{}}%
}}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Remove the section title}
\blindtext[30]
\addsec{Unnumbered section}
\blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe my question was unclear. I would like to keep the `section number`. In my example I would like to keep the `A.1` and just remove the `Remove the section title`.

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: @esdd I am sorry, but how can I totally remove page headers using `scrbook` and `scrlayer-scrpage`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou In the appendix? Then you can use `\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{\ihead*{}\ohead*{}\chead*{}\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}` or `\newcommand*{\appendixmore}{\clearpairofpagestyles\KOMAoptions{headsepline=false}}` if there should also be nothing in the footer.

Comment: @esdd I am sorry, but I meant for the whole document. I found that `plain.scrheadings` option of `scrlayer-scrpage` did what I want, am I right? or should it be done another way?

Comment: @ DiaaAbidou If you do not add header entries to `plain.scrheadings` or `plain` then you can use `\pagestyle{plain}` *after* loading `scrlayer-scrpage`. This package redefines `plain` as an alias of `plain.scrheadings`. (But maybe you want to ask an own question with a MWE.)

Answer (score 5):

I also suggest the use of `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `scrpage2`....

About your question, you can issue

```
\lohead{\thesection\autodot}
```

just after

```
\chapter{Appendix}
```

to obtain what you want.

MWE

```
\documentclass[headsepline, open=right,twoside=true, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Here I want the headers}
\blindtext[12]

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}
\lohead{\thesection\autodot}

\section{Remove the section title}
\blindtext[12]


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]